Need help in fixing regex pattern to find strings which contains invalid escape sequence but not defined as raw string
I'm attempting to create a regex pattern that can iterate over every content of the file and look for strings that Flake8 has a labelled as W605 which contains that indicate include an invalid escape sequence.
In other words, my goal is to locate certain strings and turn them into raw strings by appending {r{ to the beginning of  those strings.
Now, I came up with this basic pattern:
(?<!r)([\"\'])(.*?)[\\](.*?)([\"\'])

Which works for the below scenarios(Edit: These below lines are literal contents of file):
test1 = re.compile('^(.*?)\test1?$', re.S)   # matches correctly

test2 = re.compile(r'^(.*?)\test2?$', re.S)  # not matches, which is correct behaviour as it is defined as a raw string

test3 = re.compile("^(.*?)\test3?$", re.S)   # matches correctly

test4 = re.compile(r"^(.*?)\test4?$", re.S)  # not matches, which is correct behaviour as it is defined as a raw string

However, it also matches the string below, which is problematic::
test5.setdefault('test5', re.search('^(.*?)\test5?$', '').groups()[0])

Though, it also should selecting 'test5'it should ideally not match that one. We got the whole entire match as.follow: 'test5', re.search('^(.*?)\test5?$'.
This is the point at which I am unable to match the VALID strings exclusively.
This is the regex101: https://regex101.com/r/no99Sl/1
If anyone can help me out in this, I will be grateful.

There is nothing wrong with '^(.*?)\test1?$': \t is a valid escape sequence. And what if your string has a double backslash? And what if your string literal has escaped quotes? ...etc.

Practically: doesn't Flake8 give file names and line numbers, and can't you then just edit the files manually and add an "r" in front of them (or remove the offending backslash)?

Actually, there are thousand of files which have hundreds of lines of code. So, it is very difficult hence I am opting for this automation.

You should try this tool : https://regex-generator.olafneumann.org/  It's an interactive online tool where you select which part of a text you want to keep and it build a regrex from your selection. But I don't think you can achive what you ask just by regrex. Good luck

Could you make use of raw_s = repr(s).strip("'") to make a raw string.

No, I can't do that. Because I have to loop through all the content of python file and then using regex pattern find the problematic strings and convert it into raw strings.

All your regex101 tests are wrong, you must ALWAYS match TEXT patterns against TEXT, not string literals.
